git fetch with reference repository downloads files from server
I have a large git repository on a remote server (BitBucket, not sure if important) with quite bad internet connection.
Besides of many developer/feature/test branches on the server there is a group of release branches release/rel01, release/rel02, release/rel03, ..., release/rel11, ... (about 20).
For repeated checkout of release branches (by jenkins jobs) I created a local reference repository by
mkdir /scratch/reference.git
cd /scratch/reference.git
git init --bare
git remote add --no-tags origin ...url...
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master'
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/release/*:refs/remotes/origin/release/*'
git fetch

When I then try to create a clone with this reference repository by
mkdir /scratch/clone
cd /scratch/clone
git init
echo /scratch/reference.git/objects >.git/objects/info/alternates
git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- ...url... +refs/heads/release/*:refs/remotes/origin/release/*

still a part of the objects is downloaded from the git server resulting in few GB in .git/objects. The server branches were not updated in the meantime.
When I do a "git gc" all my local objects are removed again because these files are then found as expected in the reference repository and .git/objects is empty again (about 20kB).
Curiously if a fetch the branches one-by-one (+refs/heads/release/rel1:refs/remotes/origin/release/rel01, rel02, rel03 or rel*1, rel*2,...) usually no files are downloaded and then the rel* fetch also downloads no file.
How can I avoid that a fetch of the full set of release branches at once does not download any objects from the server when the reference repository is up-to-date?
I already re-created the reference repository from scratch and find a solution by google, but "reference" is used too often for git branch references and I only found problems about missing branches during fetch. Also checking git traces did not help because they are too complex to read and I can reproduce the issue only with our large repository.
